# Animate position of LI when clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, position, html-lists

I'm sure I'm missing something stupid here but I cannot see it.
What is supposed to happen is that, with a vertical list, when a LI is clicked it animates right 10px, if another LI is clicked then it moves back and the clicked LI moves right.
This works fine going down the list but if I go back to a previous LI the previous selected one moves back as it should but the clicked LI doesn't animate, so when you click back and forth the LI's keep going further back

```
$("#navig li").click(function(){
$("#navig li.selected").animate({ 
        left: "-=10px",
      }, 300 );
    $("#navig li.selected").removeClass("selected")

    $(this).addClass("selected")
    $(this).animate({ 
        right: "-=10px",
      }, 300 );
})
```

Comment: where is your click event ?, js code?

Comment: $("#navig li").click(function(){

Comment: always adjust `left` property, don't mix `left` and `right`

Comment: Got it, should be : "+=10" and right: "-=10" consecutively

Comment: charlietfl you are right, either left or right but swap the -/+ but cannot accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you adjust `left` either plus or minus, do the opposite for other condition but do it to same position property `left`.

Answer (score 0):

do you need something like this ?

[**http://jsfiddle.net/v3LWL**](http://jsfiddle.net/v3LWL)

```
$("#navig li").click(function(){
    var $this  = $(this),
        el = $this.siblings().filter(".selected");

    el.animate({left: 0}, 300, function(){
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
    });

    $this.animate({left: 10}, 300, function(){
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });

});
```

Comment: I'm curious, would it be better to have it as part of the css?

Comment: if you do not care of IE7/Ie8, which doesn't support transition, I would use css way

Comment: Thanks for that.  I played around with it a bit but didn't like the aesthetics of waiting for the green background on the LI to appear and I think adding a seperate class just for the animation is just making more work.